# Google Developers Console - Function to get the Project ID?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to make one of my Google-Apps-Scripts user-friendly. The script needs an API activation in the Google Developers Console.

Is it maybe possible to get the Project ID?
I want to create a direct link to the needed API-Page.

e.g.:

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/*** project id ***/apiui/apiview/static_maps_backend/overview
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You're in lucky, Google released an update 2 days ago with that function:

`ScriptApp.getProjectKey();`

Comment: The project key isn't the project id. The id is only numeric. If I insert the key into the URL, the API project page can't be found.